# Why constants' property or value aren't constant

Tags: javascript, variables, constants

[image: node.js screenshot]

I am learning basics of JavaScript again and want to know how actually JavaScript applies in my code. As you can see above, why constants' property or value aren't constant? and is there a way to prevent editing properties or values in future of code?

Comment: The `const` only applies to the variable itself. You cannot change the value of `sampleArray`, but you can freely modify the contents of the object it references.

Comment: Thank you for replying. and Yes, I can see that I cannot re-assign value of constant. However I want to know how to make constant all values. It is just I can't do? If it is like just reference, that all :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What does `const` mean?

If a variable is declared using `const` keyword it means **it can't be assigned to new value**. It doesnot mean that you can't modify it. Changing the properties of object is modifying.

#### Solution

If you want an object not to change you can use [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

```js
let someObj = {};
someObj.prop = 1; //setting prop to '1'

Object.freeze(someObj); //after this line you can't modify object
someObj.prop = "changed"; //prop will remain '1'
console.log(someObj)
```

**Note:** `Object.freeze()` is a shallow freeze means that if there are nested objects they can be still modified. Consider the example below.

```js
const obj = {
  upper:"something",
  nested:{
    nestProp:"this is nest prop"
  }
}
Object.freeze(obj);

obj.upper = 'new' //can't be changed
obj.nested.nestProp = 'new' //will be changed

console.log(obj)
```

Now this problem can be solved using recursion.

```js
function completeFreeze(obj){
  Object.freeze(obj);
  for(let key in obj){
    if(typeof obj[key] === "object"){
      completeFreeze(obj[key])
    }
  }
}

const obj = {
      upper:"something",
      nested:{
        nestProp:"this is nest prop"
      }
}

completeFreeze(obj);

obj.nested.upper = 'new' //will not be changed

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: It should be noted that `Object.freeze()` is a "shallow" freeze; it does not freeze the whole object graph.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for information. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Constants in Javascript will prevent the variable reassigning but not on its properties.

```
const item = { foo: 0 };

item.foo = 1 // Works
item = { bar: 0 } // Error
```

If you want to prevent this you can use Object.freeze for objects

```
const item = { foo: 0 };

Object.freeze(item);
item.foo = 1; // Won't modify its property
```

Comment: Constants in Javascript will prevent the variable **mutation** but not its properties. I think mutation and modifying are same. mutation means changing in properties. A better word may be assigning

Comment: Yes, you're right it was not the proper term, I've edited it :)